# Google Maps Android как переместить дефолтный значек компаса на карте?

Tags: android, google-maps

На карте Google Maps для Android показывается стандартный значек компаса в левом верхнем углу, как переместить его в левый нижний над иконкой логотипа Google?

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь никак. Либо свое делать, либо смириться с его местоположением.

C [этого](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-compass-code-example.html) можно будет начать свою реализацию компаса.